# Is there any setting in the Salesforce account where we can configure the fixed number of platform events to be generated at a given single point?

Tags: streaming-api, app-development

We are developing an application that consumes the Platform events generated by the Salesforce application. Our application consumes a salesforce streaming API to listen to new platform events.  Currently, suppose a user has generated 5k events, the application is receiving all 5k events at once.  We want to check if there is any property in the nforce client or in the salesforce account setting that we can configure and get these large number of events to be delivered in batches.

Comment: Are these Change Data Capture Events or custom event channels?

Comment: These are platform events.